# What does もの mean in this sentence?

Tags: formal-nouns

In the following sentence, does もの mean "person" (qualified by 1人あたり) or "thing" (as in "the 費用 thing")。

> 上記費用は1人あたりのものですか？

For reference, below are the definitions I have for もの:

> 物  もの  (n,uk) thing; object; the natural thing; a frequently done thing; used to express emotional involvement; used in giving a reason; (P)
>   者   もの  (n) person (rarely used w.o. a qualifier); (P)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 「上記費用{じょうきひよう}は[1人]{ひとり}あたりの**もの**ですか？」

In this sentence, 「もの」 is used in order to avoid repeating the word 「費用」 because it would sound fairly awkward to use 「費用」 twice in such a very short sentence.

> "Are the expenses above per person?"

Likewise, I am sure it would sound clumsy if I said in English:

"Are the expenses above the expenses for one person?"

Comment: Trick question: I learnt that 「こと」 generally refers to something more concrete than 「もの」, like, a 「もの」is a general concept, while a 「こと」 is a 「もの」but with a concrete context, such as a precise date and place. In this situation, I'd argue that the expenses 「費用」 have already been precised, and the speaker is talking about something determined. So, how about saying "1人あたりの**こと**ですか？" instead?

Comment: @Rightleg 「上記費用は1人あたりの**こと**ですか？」とは言わないですね・・　「こと」はそういう使い方しません。eg 「この指輪は母にもらった指輪です」→ ◎「この指輪は母にもらった**もの**です」 ×「この指輪は母にもらったことです」

Comment: @Chocolate 「この指輪は母にもらったことです」 definitely sounds strange, but assuming the explanation I got from my teacher (as I commented above) is more or less accurate, I don't really grasp why 「1人あたりのことですか？」 is wrong (although it does feel weird)

Comment: Hmm.. 上記費用は一人あたりの**費用**ですか？ can be rephrased 上記費用は一人当たりの**もの**ですか？ but not 上記費用は一人当たりの**こと**ですか？ (←sounds wrong) for the same reason as why この指輪は母にもらった**指輪**です can be rephrased この指輪は母にもらった**もの**です but not この指輪は母にもらった**こと**です (← sounds wrong). We don't use こと that way.. 前方照応的に反復の代用語として使わないです。「ジョージア州の田舎で話される英語は、インディアナ州の田舎で話されている**もの**とは全く違います」The English spoken in rural Georgia is quite different from **that** of rural Indiana. の「もの」は「こと」にできないです。